# Prove that every unbounded sequence contains a subsequence that tends to inifnity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I know the issue has already been addressed in other posts, but I want to ask if the proof I constructed is correct - I'm not confident with proofs.

> If the sequence (x<sub>n</sub>)<sub>n</sub> is unbounded, then by
>   definition
>
> ∀M>0, ∃n∈$\mathbb{N}$ s.t.|x<sub>n</sub>| $\geq$ M.
>
> To construct a subsequence
>   (x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>)<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub> that tends to plus
>   infinity select the stricly increasing sequence of natural numbers
>   (k<sub>n</sub>)<sub>n</sub> such that
>   (x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>)<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>  is increasing,
>   thus ∀M>0, ∃n∈$\mathbb{N}$ s.t. x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub> $\geq$ M.
>
> To construct a subsequence
>   (x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>)<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub> that tends to
>   minus infinity select the stricly increasing sequence of natural
>   numbers (k<sub>n</sub>)<sub>n</sub> such that
>   (x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>)<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub>  is decreasing,
>   thus ∀M>0, ∃n∈$\mathbb{N}$ s.t. x<sub>k<sub>n</sub></sub> $\leq$ M.

Is it strong enough? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction is not complete. It is merely restating what you have to prove. In fact if a sequence is unbounded there is no guarantee that there exists two subsequences, one tending to $\infty$ and the other to $-\infty$. Is $x_n$ is not bounded above choose $n_1$ such that $x_{n_1} >1$. Then choose $n_2$ such that $x_{n_2} >2$ and so on . By induction you get $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $x_{n_k}>k$ for all $k$ which implies $x_{n_k} \to \infty$. Use a similar argument if the given sequence is unbounded below.

Comment: I got back to the problem and was trying to visualize the construction of the subsequence. The subsequence thus constructed is not necessarily strictly increasing, right?

Comment: @erised You can make it strictly increasing also. For example choose $n_2$ such that  $x_{n_2}>2$ and $x_{n_2}>x_{n_1}$, and so on.